# Is there a way to full screen the output of my Google Colaboratory code?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I don't think there's much more detail as to what I'm asking. At least not more than in the "title", here it is in case you can't see it: Is there a way to full screen the output of my Google Colaboratory code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized that you can go to the bottom left corner of the screen and click the button (if you hover over you see that it says "command palette"), then search "fullscreen" you find the button that says view output "fullscreen". You have to start the program before full screening though.

Comment: Have you found a way to automatically have Colab show your output as fullscreen without you having to manually select "View output fullscreen" once the code is finished running? There may not be a way to do this, but it would be really nice

Comment: Is there a setting to see inline full-screen output in Colab?